# Count level 3 of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible without iterating the array?

```
$arr = array(
         'section1' => array(
                         5  => array(1, 2, 3),
                         25 => array(4, 5),
                         34 => array(10, 12),

                       ),

         'section2' => array(
                         45 => array(1, 42, 3),                             
                         64 => array(10, 2, 5, 95),
                       ),

         'section3' => array(
                         5 =>  array(1, 2, 3, 5, 2),
                         25 => array(4, 5, 14),
                         34 => array(17),
                       ),



       );

$count = 0;

foreach($arr as $section)
  foreach($section as $subsection)
    foreach($subsection as $entries)      
      $count++;

echo $count; // 23
```

It works but I dont want to iterate trough the entire array just to count some elements...

Comment: @Yan the number of elements in all the innermost arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`count()`](http://php.net/count).

If you need a total of all elements from all levels:

```
count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

If you only need to count the ones on the third level:

```
foreach($arr as $section)
  foreach($section as $subsection)
    $count += count($subsection);
```

Comment: No, you had it right the first time - won't `COUNT_RECURSIVE` count _all_ elements at all levels?

Comment: @Michael, apparently so. Isn't that the desired behavior? Added the previous approach just in case.

Comment: No, only the innermost arrays were to be counted.

Comment: In my actual code level3 has arrays as values, not numbers. I used numbers here just to make the code more readable. I think that using COUNT_RECURSIVE will further count my array values...

Comment: @Alex, I see. Yes indeed, then take a look at the second example.

Comment: @Alex, if you need the elements from a specific level, unfortunately you still need to do *some* iterations. This should be more efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

Anything's possible right?  ;-)

I'd see two ways you could do this without iterating and one would be to evaluate the print_r($main_array) value perhaps counting the "(" to reach the desired depth.

--

The other way would be store the data as JSON, so you can "walk" the tree, plus it's native in javascript so very efficient with dot notation.

```
"somefield":["anotherfield":["yetanother":value], "woohoo":["yahoo":value]]]  (excuse me if not well-formed just on the fly)
```

Then you parse JSON and reference like:  myval = somefield.anotherfield.yetanother;  // myval = value

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the part about counting... doh!  Again, however, you could extract inner array in JSON and count that, our a regex on exploded array but more complex than it's worth.

Comment: I think my SO is broken I'm seeing your answer on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491508/count-level-3-of-an-array

Comment: And the question was "is this possible" and answer is yes, but various ways to accomplish it.  Return question would be why, of course, but that wasn't the question.  ;-)

Comment: Forgive me (lol) I assume your answer is totally brilliant but for me it's in totally the wrong page :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's my aproach to this conundrum!

```
<?php
$arr = array(
     'section1' => array(
                     5  => array(1, 2, 3),
                     25 => array(4, 5),
                     34 => array(10, 12),

                   ),

     'section2' => array(
                     45 => array(1, 42, 3),                             
                     64 => array(10, 2, 5, 95),
                   ),

     'section3' => array(
                     5 =>  array(1, 2, 3, 5, 2),
                     25 => array(4, 5, 14),
                     34 => array(17),
                   ),



   );

function count_all($array)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v))
        {
            $count += count_all($v);
        }
        else {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo count_all($arr);
```

Comment: I don't see why this got downvoted when it acheives the right result, fair enough it's not as clean as the other answer but come on you small petty man